# Find different index in arrays compare

Tags: java

I'm trying to learn a bit Java with tutorials and currently I'm struggling with piece of code where I should find on which index is difference between arrays (if there is difference at all)

My code

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

int[] arrOne = Arrays.stream(scanner.nextLine().split(" ")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
int[] arrTwo = Arrays.stream(scanner.nextLine().split(" ")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
int sumArrOne = 0;
int index = 0;
boolean diff = false;

for (int k : arrOne) {
   if (Arrays.equals(arrOne, arrTwo)) {
       sumArrOne += k;
   } else {
       for (int i : arrTwo) {
           if (k != i) {
              index = i;
              diff = true;
               break;
           }
       }
   }
}
if (diff) {
    System.out.println("Found difference at " + index + " index.");
} else {
    System.out.println("Sum: " + sumArrOne);
}
```

So, if arrays are identical I'm sum array elements in `arrOne`. If they are not identical -> must show at which index they are not.

With this code when I input

```
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 4 3 5
```

I should get that difference is at index `2` instead I've got index `1`.

I'm not quite sure why and would be glad if someone point me out where is my mistake.

Comment: You've got a nested loop in which you're comparing element N of arrTwo with element M of arrOne. So the first difference is between arrOne[0] and arrTwo[1].

Comment: I don't see it this way. How I understand it is that first difference is exactly on arrOne[2] and arrTwo[2]. How you reach arrOne[0] and arrTwo[1]? Sorry but I can see this while I debugging

Comment: Because `for (int k : arrOne)` looks at _each_ element of arrOne from 0 onwards, and for _each_ element you then have `for (int i : arrTwo)` which also looks at each element in arrTwo. So in the first iteration of the outer loop and the second iteration of the inner loop, you're comparing the arrays at different indices.

Comment: Oh, now when you explain it like this it actually makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your code. Looks like you're misunderstanding the concept of indexes yet.

Use *one common* index to check with in both arrays, in my example it's simply called `i`:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BadArray {

    static private final int INVALID_INDEX = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        try (final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);) {


            final int[] arrOne = Arrays.stream(scanner.nextLine().split(" ")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
            final int[] arrTwo = Arrays.stream(scanner.nextLine().split(" ")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
            int sumArrOne = 0;
            int diffIndex = INVALID_INDEX;

            final int minLen = Math.min(arrOne.length, arrTwo.length);
            for (int i = 0; i < minLen; i++) {
                sumArrOne += arrOne[i];
                if (arrOne[i] != arrTwo[i]) {
                    diffIndex = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (diffIndex != INVALID_INDEX) {
                System.out.println("Found difference at " + diffIndex + " index.");
            } else if (arrOne.length != arrTwo.length) {
                System.out.println("Arrays are equal but have different length!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Sum: " + sumArrOne);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I also put the scanner into a try-resource-catch to handle resource releasing properly.

Note you could also do the array lengths comparison right at the start if different array lengths play a more crucial role.

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly even that I don't know what are some parts of it. For example `final`, `INVALID_INDEX`, and this try block but I guess I will get there too soon.

Comment: The `INVALID_INDEX` is a constant, so I can check whether the for loop has actually set the index variable. If it was set, `diffIndex` will have a value from `0 to minLen-1`. I could also check against that. Or throw the message right in the loop when I find the difference, and then exit. Or I could also define `Integer diffIndex = null;` and check against `if (diffIndex != null) {`. That's basically all the same, but I wanted to stick a bit closer to your solution and show how it's done properly. vsfDawg simply uses `-1` to indicate bad index.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to find out which index has the first difference so you should iterate via the index rather than using a for-each loop (aka enhanced for loop).  The following method should work for this.

```
/**
 * Returns the index of the first element of the two arrays that are not the same.
 * Returns -1 if both arrays have the same values in the same order.
 * @param left an int[]
 * @param right an int[]
 * @return index of difference or -1 if none
 */
public int findIndexOfDifference(int[] left, int[] right) {
  // short-circuit if we're comparing an array against itself
  if (left == right) return -1;
  for (int index = 0 ; index < left.length && index < right.length ; ++index) {
    if (left[index] != right[index]) {
      return index;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you compare, where the indexes are different, not the values at the indexes. Also your code has several other issues. I'll try to go through them step by step:

```
// compare the whole array only once, not inside a loop:
diff = !Arrays.equals(arrOne, arrTwo));
if (!diff) {
    // do the summing without a loop
    sumArrOne = Arrays.stream(arrOne).sum();
} else {
    // find the difference
    // it could be the length
    index = Math.min(arrOne.length, arrTwo.length); 
    // or in some different values
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) { // do a loop with counter
        if (arrOne[i] != arrTwo[i]) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't matter that I set `index` here above the loop as it's value will be overwritten anyways inside the loop, if relevant.